# Difference between 'active' and 'disabled'

Tags: wordpress, 4.7.6

I have set up custom fields for an event. There are multiple choice check boxes for field trips during the event. Some of the trips have reached the max number of participants and I need to stop additional sign ups. Please clarify the difference between the 'active' check box setting and the 'disable' menu item for multiple choice items. I want to hide the option but retain all current option data.

Comment: Are you sure these aren't the same thing? If you uncheck "active" doesn't that "disable" the field?

Answer (score 4):

The "Disable" and "Enable" menu items toggle the option's `is_active` field. The "Active?" checkbox does the same.

Answer (score 2):

A bit off-topic but if you want to limit the number of places for an option, instead of creating a custom field, you could create a price field item with price option and specify Max Participants.

This way, the option will be disabled from the list of choice when the limit has been reached.

The drawback of this method is that it's difficult right now to search / report based on the chosen price option.